# Visual Studio 2017 keeps recompiling stdafx.h needlessly?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, precompiled-headers

I have a Visual Studio 2017 C++ project which uses precompiled headers (stdafx.h).

My (simplified) file structure is as follows:

```
header1.hpp
header2.hpp
stdafx.h -> includes header1.hpp
code1.cpp -> includes stdafx.h
code2.cpp -> includes stdafx.h and header2.hpp
```

To avoid any ambiguity, by saying `includes header1.hpp`, I mean there is a line `#include <header1.hpp>` in the file.

1. After I modify `stdafx.h`, all three files `stdafx.h`, `code1.cpp` and `code2.cpp` are recompiled (as expected).
2. After I modify `code1.cpp`, only `code1.cpp` is recompiled (as expected).
3. After I modify `header2.cpp`, all three files `stdafx.h`, `code1.cpp` and `code2.cpp` are recompiled (**not expected!**).

I would have expected item 3 to compile only `code2.cpp`, and not everything else.

A possible reason for this behavior would be that the build manager can't inspect and follow `#include` directives, so it simply recompiles everything if any header file is modified.

Since my project is quite large, recompiling all the files like `code1.cpp` takes up a significant amount of time.  I purposely did not include `header2.hpp` from `stdafx.h` because I know I would modify `header2.hpp` often and only `code2.cpp` needs to use it.  (`header2.hpp` is a template library that has functions only `code2.cpp` needs.)

Is this behavior expected, and what can I do to get Visual Studio to recognize that the other files need not be recompiled?

Comment: That seems like expected behavior - Precompiled headers are meant to be recompiled whenever a header changes.

Comment: Is there any way to tell Visual Studio not to recompile the precompiled headers then?

Comment: Simple - don't use precompiled headers.

Comment: In what order does code2.cpp include stdafx.h and header2.hpp? AFAIK, everything that comes before the `#include <stdafx.h>` line is considered to be part of the precompiled headers. So header2.hpp should be included after.

Comment: @Thebluefish If I don't use precompiled headers then wouldn't all `.cpp` files still get compiled when I modify a header file?

Comment: @KarstenKoop The first line of code2.cpp is `#include <stdafx.h>`. `#include <header2.hpp>` is on the following line.

Comment: The cpp files should only be recompiled if one of the header they `#include` get changed.

Comment: @Thebluefish I'll give that a try.  But that means I'll have to sacrifice the speed boost of precompiled headers then.  Also, if cpp files are only recompiled if one of their `#include`s gets changed then it means Visual Studio is smart enough to decipher include directives.  In that case it seems inconsistent and strange that it doesn't decipher include directives for stdafx.h.

Comment: The compiler never compiles a .h file, only ever a .cpp file.  If that .cpp file #includes a .h file then you might see that happening, albeit that you did not tell us exactly how you saw that.  One of the source files must have the /Yc compile option, it creates the .pch file so other .cpp files with /Yu can benefit from it.  Normally that is stdafx.cpp with the default project settings.  We can't see which of the .cpp files has that option, but it certainly sounds like it is code2.cpp.  Not a good choice.

Comment: @KarstenKoop Actually I think Visual Studio will refuse to compile the code if stdafx.h is not the first include directive.

Comment: @HansPassant My stdafx.cpp is an empty file that is unused. There isn't anything special about code2.cpp.

Comment: @HansPassant As I understand, all .h files are not compiled except stdafx.h.  Isn't this correct?

Comment: It is not correct, .h files get *included*, .cpp files get compiled.  I have no real concept of how programmers might find an empty .cpp useful, consider following common practices so you can get help with your problems.  And avoid them.

Comment: Is `header2.hpp` included by another header?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm no it is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I had disabled precompiled headers a year ago (but left `stdafx.h` and `stdafx.cpp` in the project), and when I wanted to use them again I forgot to turn on the `/Yc` and `Yu` options.

No errors were given, and Visual Studio had been compiling `stdafx.cpp` like a regular .cpp file.

Also, I had the wrong idea of how precompiled headers worked.  I thought `stdafx.h` gets *compiled* by itself (then dumped into those .cpp files that `#include "stdafx.h"` via some intermediate representation), but actually the file that gets compiled is `stdafx.cpp` (and while compiling produces the .pch file).  (As per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17903843/what-is-stdafx-cpp-file-that-is-created-automatically-in-a-new-c-project-in-vi).)

After turning on the precompiled header options, when I modify `header2.cpp`, only `code2.cpp` gets recompiled, as I would like.

Also, compilation times are now significantly faster.